# How to import and style svg i hono.dev?

Tags: svg, jsx, deno, tsx, hono

Does anyone know how to import to tsx an svg file in deno (hono.dev framework)? The point is that it can still be styled:

```css
.myclass {
    fill: var(--sl-color-primary-500);
}
```